# Xcode renames files when compiling?

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, rename

Every time I compile my iPhone project, Xcode renames my `Default.png` to `default.png`

The file name in my project is Default.png, so it's correct in my project. It gets renamed somewhere in the compile process; **is there any way to stop Xcode from renaming this file?**

It's the *only* file that gets renamed for some reason, and my app wont display the splash screen when put on my device unless I manually rename it back to `Default.png`.

Comment: Did you add any build phases of your own?

Comment: I havent added any other options, nor messed with compression options for PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silly mistake I made was adding an image called default.png as an Icon inside my app, so it was taking it as the only default.png. I simply renamed my image(icon) to _default.png and my splash (Default.png) didnt rename!